# To use GenerationType=Sequence across all databases

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are writing a library which will include Spring boot, JPA and hibernate as the JPA vendor. Since it is a library we do not want to write database type specific code in the library. So we are doing a POC on the same.

- We understand GenerationType.SEQUENCE is the best ID generation mechanism for Oracle especially 'Pooled' mechanism so that it reduces the DB calls.
- We understand GenerationType.IDENTITY is not supported by Oracle (Is it correct?).
- We undestand MySql supports GenerationType.Table and not 'Sequences'.

Given all these, how can we write a generic code which will use GenerationType.SEQUENCE (most preferably: pooled) in Oracle and GenerationType.TABLE in MySQL.

Our JPA test entity is as below,

```
package cxc.spring.test.db;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor( staticName = "of" )
@ToString
@Entity
@Table( name = "CXC_TEST" )
public class TestTable{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "ID" )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "post_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "post_sequence",
            sequenceName = "post_sequence",
            allocationSize = 3
    )
    private Long id;
    @Column( name = "\"VALUE\"" )
    private String value;

    @Column( name = "LCHG_USER_ID" )
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column( name = "RCRE_USER_ID" )
    private String createdBy;
}
```

This works fine in Oracle. Is there any way to default this to GenerationType.TABLE in MySQL, or is there any other way?

If we use, GenerationType.AUTO, in Oracle does it default to sequence but in that case the 'Pooled' feature with allocation size will not be used effectively making the allocation size to 1.

Comment: you may keep `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` strategy for both databases: Hibernate does know MySQL do not support sequences and should switch to using tables automatically.

Comment: Ok in that case what is the difference between AUTO and using SEQUENCE? Both will default to supporting GenerationType?

Comment: afaik, in Hibernate 4 `AUTO` was meaning [`native`](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-hibernate-native-id-generator/) - that is up to JPA provider implementation how to interpret `AUTO` strategy. On the other hand emulating sequences via tables is a Hibernate feature, though other implementations have something similar: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_sequence.html

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5. So when I use Generator as SEQUENCE, mysql looks for all_sequences, which frankly I dont know what it is. It gives an error as below,

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'equicadm.all_sequences' doesn't exist

So this means it uses the same sequence table? Is it defaulting to 'TABLE' or 'IDENTITY' is also not clear..

Comment: `all_sequences` is Oracle's view, have you changed dialect (`hibernate.dialect`) prior switching to MySQL?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov All your comments were helpful. GenerationType.SEQUENCE worked for mysql and I was using the wrong dialect.  Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I could use the below annotation even for mysql and it defaulted to Table.

```
@Id
        @Column( name = "ID" )
        @GeneratedValue(
                        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                        generator = "post_sequence"
        )
        @SequenceGenerator(
                        name = "post_sequence",
                        sequenceName = "post_sequence",
                        initialValue=1000,
                        allocationSize = 3
        )
```

Only thing is we need to create a table as below in mysql..

```
CREATE TABLE `post_sequence` (
  `sequence_name` varchar(30),
  `next_val` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I am still not clear about sequence_name column but the annotation worked fine for Oracle, mysql and H2